# UIScrollView always bounce upwards and does not show scroll bar in iphone

Tags: iphone

This is probably simple but I do not seem to get it to work. I have a view and inside it I have a scroll view and inside it I have a view with some labels and a button. the height of the text inside the labels changes according to some condition so I need to scroll down to see it. But whenever I try to scroll down it bounce back up without giving me a chance to view the rest of the view.

Basically, I want when I scroll down, the view to remain down as it normally should. Besides I do not see the scroll bar at all when I'm scrolling.

I know I probably do not understand how scroll views work, so I'd appreciate any help to explain to me the behavior of scroll views.

P.S. I built my whole view in a nib file and this specific setup That I mentioned at the beginning is based on a suggestion from one question I read here.

Thanks, Mohsen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set content size of your scroll view

```
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(360,1000)];
```

you can make the content size dynamic as per your calculation.

Comment: Thank you so much. That really helped a lot. I was struggling with that for long. Thanks.